# Nesting within Constraint Layout

Tags: java, android

I am new to android app development and trying to build a simple employee management app. The aim is reuse as many activities as possible. Now, I basically have four activities - a registration form, a list of all the employees (which basically uses multiple instances of a single employee record layout), one to update a record and one to delete a record. I plan to use a single activity for update (which will use the layout of the registration form) and delete (which will use the single record layout) operations.
To achieve this, I want to enable the registration form layout for update and the disable it and enable the single record layout with an additional 'delete' button to delete a record, and vice - versa. Since I am using a constraint layout, I want to include a container which holds the necessary layout.

I tried using a constraint layout as the container inside a constraint layout, but it is causing problems when I try to constraint the inner layout with the objects int the outer layout. I tried to code the constraints in xml as well as via mouse click and drag. Basically I am unable to constraint the inner constraint layout with objects in the outer constraint layout.

Xml for update/delete activity which I intend to reuse:

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
       android:text="Enter ID"
       android:textColor="#000"
       app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="number"
       android:text="Name"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       android:background="@drawable/form_drawable"
       android:paddingEnd="8dp"
       android:paddingStart="8dp"
       android:paddingLeft="8dp"
       android:paddingRight="8dp"
       android:textColor="#FFF"/>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Xml for a single employee record:

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="#000"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/form_drawable"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Designation"
                android:textColor="#000"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText3"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/form_drawable"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Address"
                android:textColor="#000"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText4"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/form_drawable"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Phone
"

                android:textColor="#000"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/form_drawable"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="ID"
                android:textColor="#000"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Xml for registration form:

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fields marked with * are compulsory." />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFirstName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="First Name *"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/form_drawable"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:text="MAnish"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMiddleName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Middle Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etMiddleName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/form_drawable"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:text="JOshi"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="24sp"  />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLastName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Last Name *"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etLastName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/form_drawable"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Address *"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/form_drawable"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Phone *"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPhone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/form_drawable"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDesignation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Designation *"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etDesignation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/form_drawable"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SAVE"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:background="@drawable/crud_btns"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Within the update/delete layout I want to input an id permanently.
Then, according to the required operation, I want to display the registration form with all the fields filled in with the previous data so as to update it. If the operation is to delete, then I just want to show the details of the employee with the given ID (so the user doesn't delete the wrong record) as well as a delete button.
Any inputs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not using nested `constraint layout` here. you are using three different constraint layout rather. you have to create one **main** constraint layout and inside that **main layout** you have to design your three constraint layouts.

> Your code will be like

```
#1st constraint-layout start(main-layout)# 

    #2nd constraint-layout start# 
        //xml code here 
     #2nd constraint-layout End# 

     #3rd constraint-layout start# 
        //xml code here 
     #3rd constraint-layout End# 

      #4th constraint-layout start# 
         //xml code here 
       #4th constraint-layout End# 

  #1st constraint-layout End(main-layout)#
```

So basically include your all three `constraint layouts` in one **Main** constraint-Layout